# MySQL: Where clause base on result from IF statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the query:

```
select IF ((t1.emp_id IS NOT NULL), t2.username, '') 
from t1, t2 
where t1.user_id = "285" AND t2.id = t1.emp_id
```

It works fine, but if `t1.emp_id` **is NULL** it will not return result because of this part `AND t2.id = t1.emp_id` but this part secure me that I will get exact `t2.id` if `t1.emp_id` **is not NULL**. Is there a way to handle it ?

The idea is if `t1.emp_id` is not null then to return t2.username based on relation **t1.emp_id = t2.id** but in this case when **t1.emp_id** is null it doesn't return result, because of last part of query. If I remove last part it will not returns me exact row from t2.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would all help.  Why are you not using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `LEFT JOIN`.  My best guess is:

```
select coalesce(t2.username, '')
from t1 left join
     t2 
     on t2.id = t1.emp_id 
where t1.user_id = 285;
```

Answer (score 0):

use following query & try again.

```
select t1.emp_id, t2.username
from t1, t2 
where t1.user_id = "285" AND t2.id = t1.emp_id AND t1.emp_id is NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This will not work, because I want to return results, whether or not there is `t1.emp_id`